# Cannot Passing Express Js Router Request and Respond to Class Method

Tags: javascript, express, babeljs, es6-class

I have a problem when creating express JS router.

I can not passing req and res to my class method.

**Not Work** `app.get('/', controller.index)`

**Work** `app.get('/', (res,req) => controller.index(req,res)`

The following is the flow of the routing that I made:
app.js (Main file) > /routes/index.js > /routes/user.route.js > /controllers/user.controller.js > /services/user.services.js

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import routes from './routes';
import db from './models';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Database Initialize
db.sequelize.sync()
.then(() => {
    console.log(" Database Connected.");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("❌ Failed Connect to Database");
})

// Router
app.use(routes);

//global dir
global.__basedir = __dirname;

app.enable("trust proxy");

app.listen(port, () => {
  // logger.info("Checking the API status: Everything is OK");
  console.log(` App listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import appRoutes from './app.routes';
import roleRoutes from './role.routes';
import userRoutes from './user.routes';
import authRoutes from './auth.routes';

const app = express();

// App Routes
app.use('/app', appRoutes);
// Role Routes
app.use('/role', roleRoutes);
// User Routes
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
// Auth Routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

export default app;
```

**routes/user.routes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import userController from '../controllers/user.controller';
import validateAuth from '../middlewares/validateAuth';

const app = express();
const controller = new userController;

app.get('/', controller.index);

export default app;
```

**controllers/user.controller.js**

```
import userServices from "../services/user.services";
import baseController from "./base.controller";

export default class userController extends baseController {
    constructor() {
        super(new userServices());
    }
}
```

**controllers/base.controller.js**

```
import response from "../helpers/response";
import lang from "../helpers/lang";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

export default class baseController {
    constructor(service) {
        this.service = service
    }

    /**
     * Index
     * Get all data with pagination
     */
    async index(res, req) {
        try {
            const data = await this.service.paginate(req.query);
            if(data) {
                return response.success({
                    res,
                    message: lang[process.env.LANG].DATA_LOADED,
                    data
                });
            } else {
                throw new Error(lang[process.env.LANG].REQUEST_FAILED);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return response.error({
                res,
                message: err.message,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**services/user.services.js**

```
import baseServices from "./base.services";
import db from "../models";

export default class userServices extends baseServices {
    constructor() {
        const attributes = [
            "roleId",
            "appId",
            "username",
            "password",
            "name",
            "phone",
            "email",
            "isActive",
        ];
        super(db.user, attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Paginate
     * @param {{
     *  search: string,
     *  limit: number,
     *  offset: number,
     *  sortBy: string,
     *  orderBy: string,
     *  user: object
     * }} data
     * return Promise
     */
    paginate(data) {
        const { search, limit, page, sortBy, orderBy, user } = data;

        const offset = limit
            ? parseInt(limit) * parseInt(page) - parseInt(limit)
            : 0;

        let filter = {};
        if (search)
            Object.assign(filter, { name: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } });

        const condition = {
            where: filter ? filter : "",
            order: sortBy ? [[sortBy, orderBy]] : [["name", "asc"]],
            limit: limit ? parseInt(limit) : 10,
            offset,
            include: ["role", "app"]
        };

        return this.model.findAndCountAll(condition);
    }
}
```

**services/base.services.js**

```
import db from "../models";
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

/**
 * Base Services Class
 */
export default class baseServices {
    constructor(model, attributes = []) {
        this.model = model;
        this.attributes = attributes
    }
}
```

**Response**

**Not Work** `app.get('/', controller.index)`

[Error Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rncao.png)

**Work** `app.get('/', (res,req) => controller.index(req,res)`

[Success Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw1qp.png)

I was try to change `const app = express()` and `const app = express.Router()`  but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things wrong here:

1. You are losing the `controller` object in the index method because of the way you're passing the index method.
2. You are doing some very confusing things with the order of the `(req, res)` arguments.

Your `controller.index()` method declares them in reverse as:

```
async index(res, req) { ... }
```

So, that's why:

```
app.get('/', controller.index)
```

doesn't work.  Because the arguments are passed as `(req, res)` by Express, but your method expects them as `(res, req)`.

Then, the reason that this works:

```
app.get('/', (res,req) => controller.index(req,res));
```

is because you reverse the argument again.

---

So, change the method to this:

```
async index(req, res) { ... }
```

so, it matches the way Express passes the arguments and then the arguments will be correct.

Then, because your `controller` object has instance data and the `index` method uses `this`, you also need to make sure the index method is getting passed it's instance properly in `this` by changing to this:

```
app.get('/', controller.index.bind(controller));
```

Comment: I was change like that but still have same problem

Comment: @SyarifMaulana - See what I added to my answer.  You also need to change to: `app.get('/', controller.index.bind(controller));.`.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the correct **MVC** pattern and repeat after me,
your **app.js** should be:

```
require ('dotenv').config();
const routes =  require('./routes');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./models');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Database Initialize
db.sequelize.sync()
.then(() => {
    console.log(" Database Connected.");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("❌ Failed Connect to Database");
})

// Router
app.use(routes);

//global dir
global.__basedir = __dirname;

app.enable("trust proxy");

app.listen(port, () => {
  // logger.info("Checking the API status: Everything is OK");
  console.log(` App listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

The **routes/index.js** file should follow the structure:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

router.use('/app', require(./app.routes"));
router.use('/role', require("./role.routes"));
router.use('/user', require("./user.routes"));
router.use('/auth', require("./auth.routes"));


module.exports = router;
```

Your all routes file should be like this

**user.routes**

```
const userController = require("whatever the location");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.post("/example", userController.controller);

module.exports = router;
```

The userController file:

```
const userServices = require("what ever the location");

const controller = async (request, response) => {
    try {
        //code goes here
        await userServices.addUser(
        {
                "name": "ALI",
                "gender": "MALE",
        }
    )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).json({
            error: "Something went wrong",
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    controller
}
```

And finally the userServices file is:

```
const user = require("what ever the location");

const addUser = async (data) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new user(data)
            .save()
            .then((data) => resolve(data))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });

}

module.exports = {
    addUser
}
```